# Facebook For Developers- Instagram Platform- Data inconsistent

Tags: facebook, instagram-api, facebook-insights

Hye. My IG insights i pulled from Facebook for developers are inconsistent with my current IG followers. Ex, insight i pulled for audience_gender_age in total is 521 but my current followers on IG is 949. Anyone else experienced it?

Comment: Docs for `audience_gender_age ` say, _"The gender and age distribution of followers for whom we have demographic data."_ - so the difference is probably those for which they _haven't_ then.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.